# Dynamic mapping for suggest field in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following dynamic mapping:

```
    "mappings": {
        "_default_": {
            "dynamic_templates": [
                {
                    "suggest_template": {
                        "mapping": {
                            "suggest": {
                                "type": "completion",
                                "index_analyzer": "simple",
                                "search_analyzer": "simple",
                                "payloads": true
                            }
                        },
                        "match": "suggest"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "properties": {}
        }    
}
```

This mapping should, as far as I understand, map all fields called suggest to the completion type.

However when I index documents all of the fields named suggest are indexed as type string:

```
"properties": {

                "suggest": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
 }
```

**Does anyone know why this mapping isn't working?**

p.s. To set this into a scope. The end use case for this is to use the completion suggester. As this mapping doesn't work I get the following error:

```
ElasticsearchException[Field [suggest] is not a completion suggest field]
```

Comment: If you need any more info just go ahead and post here and I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the problem with the mapping. The "suggest_template": and brackets should be removed.